# How can I sort sublists that are part of a list based on a single var from the sublist?

Tags: python, list, sorting, split

I'm interested in sorting a list that's formed from several sublists.

For example, I'm receiving as input the following:

```
Rus Dan 264
Pop Alin 263
Stan Darius 304
Pop Tudor 252
Rusu Alin 323
Stroe Mihai 279
Rusu Paul 268
```

I'm reading the lines:

```
for i in range(n):
    c=input("").split()
    b.append(c)
```

The result I get is:

```
[['Rus', 'Dan', '264'], ['Pop', 'Alin', '263'], ['Stan', 'Darius', '304'], ['Pop', 'Tudor', '252'], ['Rusu', 'Alin', '323'], ['Stroe', 'Mihai', '279'], ['Rusu', 'Paul', '268']]
```

I'm interested in ordering the sublists by the last number, not by char.

Any suggestions please?

I've tried to split the sublists then to make the last number int and order each sublist using .sort() but I've got several errors.

```
for sublist in n:
    for item in sublist:
        flat_list.append(item)

for i in range(n)
    flat_list[i][2]=int(flat_list[i][2])

b=flat_list.sort()

#not the exact code but something extremely similar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
data=[['Rus', 'Dan', '264'], ['Pop', 'Alin', '263'], ['Stan', 'Darius', '304'], ['Pop', 'Tudor', '252'], ['Rusu', 'Alin', '323'], ['Stroe', 'Mihai', '279'], ['Rusu', 'Paul', '268']]

print(sorted(data,key=lambda x:int(x[-1])))
```

output:

```
[['Pop', 'Tudor', '252'], ['Pop', 'Alin', '263'], ['Rus', 'Dan', '264'], ['Rusu', 'Paul', '268'], ['Stroe', 'Mihai', '279'], ['Stan', 'Darius', '304'], ['Rusu', 'Alin', '323']]
```

Comment: I switched it to

'b.sort(key=lambda x:int(x[-1]))'

So that I might also keep the data sorted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Sort using a custom key.  You can use an anonymous function:

```
data.sort(key=lambda s: int(s[2]))
```

Comment: Should data be a new list in which the sublists will be sorted? If yes, should I instead of s put b which contains my list? If so, s[2] would represent lets say the number in a sublist which has been already splitted from the big list. If I'm to keep the sublists in the list, should I work in a for with a b[i][2]?